# when we return a c++ container like vector,list. What happens?

Tags: c++, containers, return-value, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
vector<int> function(...)
{
      .......
      .......
      vector<int> C = some value;
      return C
}
int main()
{
      X = function(...)
}
```

what would the value of x be, will it be the address of C like when we return an array or would the returned value be the complete vector C copied into X. in what cases should you dynamically allocate a container? Would there be any differnce in the final X if pass the vector by reference or by value?

Comment: You return a copy of the `vector` - that's what your function is supposed to return. Also you aren't passing anything into the function so I don't understand the second question

Comment: You also need an `auto` specifier in front of the `X =...` statement.

Comment: @UnholySheep: He meant passed out (returning reference) not passed in. Returning a reference to a temp variable (local) is generally a bad idea, as that data will be unallocated when the function returns. It may crash or not, or crash only on some machines / builds. The memory might or might not still hold a valid value for a while. Don't risk that

Comment: If you return a reference (i.e. declare the function's return type `vector<int> &`) and do it like in your code, you'll get a dangling reference in the end. Local objects are destroyed when exiting their scope.

Comment: Return by moving (`return std::move(C);`). The standard containers are designed to be movable at negligible cost whenever possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller never do that.

Comment: @manni66 - Never say never without qualification. For non-template code the loss of a single move elision is not a big price to pay if you want the vector to always be moved.

Comment: @StoryTeller but the standard guarantees that it will be moved. Doing something that (definitely?) prevents optimisation to gain something that you were already guaranteed would be silly. I concur with manni.

Comment: @user2079303 - You and manni are both correct in this simple toy example. But you can have any expression in a return statement. So `return (condition ? local_a : local_b);` will give you neither copy elision nor move construction as specified by `[class.copy]`. I repeat, never say never without qualification.

Comment: @StoryTeller I yeld: Never `std::move` when implicit move is guaranteed. Only `std::move` when it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @user2079303 - No need to yield. My original comment is indeed foolish if taken at face value. You were both correct to make me re-evaluate my assertion.

Answer (score 6):

Normally whenever you return something from a function it is copied. And when this *something* has a copy constructor then it will be fired. For example arrays: they are just pointers (with trivial copy constructor) to some block of memory. So what actually is copied is only the pointer itself. But vectors are quite complicated classes. And they have copy constructors which actually copy entire content. This does not scale well.

But here's the thing: you almost never allocate vectors dynamically. In many cases (for example in your pseudo-code) the content **is not** copied due to (Named) Return Value Optimization or other [copy elision optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). It is literally the same vector.

If in some case copy elision does not fire (or you are not sure) it is still better to pass the vector by ref to the function rather then dynamically allocate it on the heap. Allocating memory in a function and then returning it to the caller is an anti-pattern (even though sometimes necessary). This causes the big problem: who is responsible for freeing the memory? You need to know the source code of the function (or at least the docs) to know that.

Another option (when copy elision does not apply) is to use `std::move` to avoid copies.

On the other hand passing vector by value will create a copy of that vector. Most certainly you want to pass it by ref or const ref.

Also I encourage you to check all those things yourself. Try printing raw pointers `&C` and `&X` to see if it is the same object.

Comment: N/RVO is mandatory in most cases come C++17. And even when it isn't, move semantics can still be made viable to pass the container cheaply.

Comment: If (N) RVO was not applied, then the standard *guarantees* move construction of the return value (from an automatic variable. Using std::move there I'd a pessimisation because it inhibits RVO.

Comment: @user2079303 That's the first time I hear about this guarantee and I find it weird. For example if you declare to return `Base` yet you return `Derived` (afaik a case when RVO does not apply). How would `std::move` work in that case? Can you point me to some resources on the topic?

Comment: You can find it in the the current C++17 draft at [[class.copy.elision](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision)]. Previous standard versions (C++11 and C++14) had those details just at [class.copy]. Anyway, it all applies to to local variables used in simple return statement.

Comment: @freakish why would you return `Derived` from a function that returns `Base`? Why not construct a `Base` in the first place? Seems to me like a convoluted and rare use case. Such move would not be implicit indeed so you would have to use `std::move`. I don't think that a move from a subobject can be elided, so it would be pointless to try to achieve NRVO.

Comment: @user2079303 Who cares why? If it can be done, then someone may do it. You stated `the standard guarantees move construction of the return value`. That's what I'm opposing. So generally it does not guarantee it. There are several conditions that have to be satisfied.

Comment: @freakish I'm stating (or intended to) that in the context of the example code in the question. In that example, the return is an id-expression of a local variable. The statement doesn't extend to all convoluted corner cases that differ from the exmaple. I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

By a pure semantic standpoint, despite of its type name, C is a plain local variable (that most likely contains three pointers: to the begin, end and capacity of the dynamic buffer containing the data).

That variable is moved in a temporary object given to the return statement that is in turn moved into the X variable to replace its content.

RVO optimization can skip the first move, by making the C variable itself to live inside the stack frame of the outer function (main - in your case).

Since you did not declare any type for X, I must assume it is already existent `std::vector<int>`, so the `=` is actually an assignment.

Since `std::vector` implement move semantics:

1. The actual inner pointers in `X` and `C` are swapped (so that `X` holds `C` content and `C` holds the old `X` content
2. `C` is destroyed

   1. `C` destructor will destroy the retained "old `X` content"

Standard library containers are themselves dynamic content managers. Allocate them, dynamically and pass them around as pointers is the biggest nonsense a C++ programmer can do. At least from 2011 onward.

If "function" does not access X in any way, further optimization can even remove the assignment at all, by making C an alias of X, so that The content of X is replaced by the one of C at the  time of its construction. the return and the = are simply removed.